Using ListSerializer inside "to_representation" of Serializer class
I want to create multiple objects based on data received in nested json array. In order to do so I created a serializers.Serializer and overriden to_representation method to use ListSerializer for serialization of newly created objects.
Simplified code look like so (for ease of reproducing by simply running python with DRF installed)
import json

from rest_framework import serializers


class Link:

    def __init__(self, title: str, description: str, url: str):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.url = url


class LinkResponseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    url = serializers.CharField()


class URLSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    url = serializers.CharField()


class LinkSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField()
    urls = URLSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        links = []
        for obj in validated_data.pop("urls", []):
            links.append(Link(url=obj["url"], **validated_data))
        return links

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return LinkResponseSerializer(instance, many=True).data


data = {
    "title": "Example",
    "description": "Exampe Description",
    "urls": [
        {"url": "https://google.com"},
        {"url": "https://yahoo.com"},
    ]
}

serializer = LinkSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()

print(json.dumps(serializer.data, indent=4))

Running this code will result in an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/.../test.py", line 54, in <module>
    print(json.dumps(serializer.data, indent=4))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/.../venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 556, in data
    return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/.../venv/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/serializer_helpers.py", line 19, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I understand that issue comes from the .data property of a serializers.Serializer which tries to use ReturnDict as a return value which initialized with a list as an argument.
I can workaround this issue by overriding .data property like so:
from rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers import ReturnList

class LinkSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField()
    urls = URLSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        links = []
        for obj in validated_data.pop("urls", []):
            links.append(Link(url=obj["url"], **validated_data))
        return links

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return LinkResponseSerializer(instance, many=True).data

    @property
    def data(self):
        self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
        return ReturnList(self._data, serializer=self)


Which will produce the desired output:
[
    {
        "title": "Example",
        "description": "Exampe Description",
        "url": "https://google.com"
    },
    {
        "title": "Example",
        "description": "Exampe Description",
        "url": "https://yahoo.com"
    }
]

But DRF Browserable API is no longer going to work if we use generic views, as it expects ReturnDict as a return type for .data property of a serializers.Serializer!
What is the right way to handle the issue? Use case doesn't seem odd to me and it feels like there has to be an easier way.

It's not a good practice to override the data property.
Each instance of the to_representation for LinkSerializer is expected to return a dict of the data, not a list as being forced in your code which is why the browsable API isn't working.
If you want to create a custom list response, then you need to modify the LinkResponseSerializer to_representation handle a list
Like:
class LinkResponseSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    url = serializers.CharField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        links = instance.all() # This should be a list and you can return it.
        return links


class LinkSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = serializers.CharField()
    urls = URLSerializer(many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        links = []
        for obj in validated_data.pop("urls", []):
            links.append(Link(url=obj["url"], **validated_data))
        return links

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return LinkResponseSerializer(instance, many=True)

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = LinkResponseSerializer

This is untested, so you should expect some errors in the code.
more details about this can be found here -> https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior
